Error while connecting to CoinDCX web-socket to fetch real-time cryptocurrency data
I'm building a project in Java and using Maven for project management. I'm trying to connect to the CoinDCX WebSocket API to fetch real-time cryptocurrency data, but I'm encountering issues.
Specifically, I'm receiving error codes 504 and 1002. The application accepts the input but fails to connect to the WebSocket. All my dependencies are correctly set up, and the JDK version is correct, but it still isn't fetching the data.
I've double-checked the WebSocket endpoint, network connectivity, and firewall settings, but the problem persists. Has anyone faced a similar issue or can provide guidance on how to resolve this connection error?

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.

I had the same 504 error i.e. server unavailable but I solved it using this options. and I'm using socket.io for this.
IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
        options.transports = new String[]{"websocket"};
        options.multiplex = false;

        socket = IO.socket("wss://stream.coindcx.com",options);
        socket.io().timeout(-1);

